# Get SIM number on android phone with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to get the phone number with **react-native-device-info **library,
What happens is if I try with the android studio emulator I capture the number, but when I do it with a physical phone it doesn't capture me.

The two permissions that I ask for on the phone are:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

```
import api from '_services/api';
import {PermissionsAndroid, Platform} from 'react-native';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

const UseSendPhoneNumber = () => {
  const sendPhoneNumber = async token => {
    if (!token || Platform.OS !== 'android') {
      return;
    }
    const hasPhoneStatePermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    );
    const hasReadSMSPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_SMS,
    );

    if (
      hasPhoneStatePermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED &&
      hasReadSMSPermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED
    ) {
      const phoneNumber = await DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber();

      if (phoneNumber) {
        await api.sendPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      }
    }
  };

  return {
    sendPhoneNumber,
  };
};

export default UseSendPhoneNumber;
```

I tried with emulators, and if it captures the data, but with physical devices it does nothing for me.

Comment: What does it return? An empty string, null, or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying for Android API version more than 29, change your permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
```

Comment: it really worked as expected. other libraries missing to add permission for READ_PHONE_NUMBERS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same while implementing for a mobile app, but after a while ***written own java module*** that can do just ***automatic sim detection*** and linked it with the react native.

I ***don't guarantee that works for every device*** out there on the market, but it does for most of them (latest ones).

You can checkout this [article](https://prajwalhaniya.hashnode.dev/how-to-get-sim-information-from-the-device-using-react-native-techletter-38) for writing java module using subscription info to get the sim details.

The above solution ***works even when you have multiple sims***. You get the information of both sims, through which you can get the phone numbers.